# Solving a function through series (SAS)

Tags: function, loops, sas, series, calculation

I need some help in checking my program in SAS that uses loops to solve a function as i am struggling. The function which i need to solve is in terms of a series expansion and it is:

> ln(1+x)

I need to evaluate the function at `x0 = 0.8` and the summation must stop when the next term is less than `0.05`.

This is what I have so far but I'm very far off from where I need to be I believe:

```
data sumseries;
numerator = x;
denom =1;
x = 0.8;
do while (tot>abs(0.05));
    numerator=x*numerator;
    denom=denom+1;
    sign=sign*-1
    term=numerator/denom;
    tot=sign*tot+term;
    output;
end;
proc print data=sumseries;
run;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Apologies if my formatting/presentation of the coding etc isn't up to scratch as I'm not familiar with this site

Edit: Change of names/values but replied answer still stands

Answer (score 1):

I'll first give you pointers with your method, then provide my preferred solution.

Your solution, updated with my fixes:

```
data q2;
  *indent please!;
  denom =1;
  x = 0.3;
  *Move this assignment to after x is assigned;
  numerator= x;
  *initialize sign;
  sign = 1;
  *initialize tot;
  tot=x;
  *need an output to start out with;
  output;
  *WHILE change to UNTIL (req. switching >  to <);
  *tot changed to term;
  do until (term < abs(0.000001));
      numerator=x*numerator;
      denom=denom+1;
      sign=sign*-1;
      term=numerator/denom;
      *you want to add (sign*term) to the total, right?;
      tot=tot + sign*term;
      output;
  end;
  *always include a RUN after data steps, even though not required;
run;

proc print data=q2;
run;
```

My preferred solution:

```
*Use the macro language to define things like starting values;
%let x=0.3;

*let us see how close we get to correct!;
%put %sysfunc(log(1.3));

data want;
  *initialize sum;
  sum = 0;

  *loop until we hit the limit.  The until here is technically unneeded;
  *but I like to include it for clarity;
  do term = 1 by 1 until (abs(new) lt 1e-6);

    *make the new value to be added (x to the power of term, divided by term;
    *times -1 to the power of term plus one to get the right value for the sign);
    new = (((&x)**term)/term) * (-1)**(term+1);
    *stop iterating if the new term would be too small;
    if abs(new) lt 1e-6 then leave;

    *add to the sum now and output;;
    sum = sum + new;
    output;
  end;
  stop;  *stop the data step loop;
run;
```

You might want to not output that last line, by the way, but that should be easy to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I really appreciate the pointers and editing in my code and also the supplying of your preferred method, its extremely helpful to see the comparison along with what i currently understand. I will try to improve me coding presentation in future but thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DIF` function to compare the difference between two items that are FIFO stacked.

Example:

Presume the fuzz (`1e-5`) will be reached within 100 iterations.

```
data quotient;
  x = 0.3;
  guard = 100;

  numerator = 1;
  denom = 0;
  sign = -1;
  sum = 0;

  * Mercator series:
  * ln(1+x) = x^1/1 - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + ... ;

  ln_1_3 = log(1+0.3);

  do iteration = 1 to guard until (iteration > 1 and abs(dif(sum)) < 1e-5);
      numerator = x * numerator;
      denom = denom + 1;
      sign = sign * -1;
      term = sign * numerator / denom;
      sum = sum + term;
      output;
  end;

  stop;
run;

proc print data=q2;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: You can, but why would you?  You have the `term` element available to check...